# Passing non ascii strings to fit_transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have this function that is fed a text document with many words. It chokes when it comes across words like the following. How do I specify the right encoding? I tried encoding = 'string', 'unicode' etc and decode_error='ignore' etc but it does not work.

co¤a
co¤azo

```
def tokenize(text):
  sentence = [text]
  ngv2 = CountVectorizer(encoding='utf-8', analyzer='word', min_df=1, stop_words='english')
  try:
     ngv2.fit_transform(sentence)
  except Exception:
     print sentence
  S = ngv2.get_feature_names()
  ngw = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', ngram_range=(3, 7), min_df=1)
  ngw.fit_transform(S)
  return ngw.get_feature_names()
```

EDIT: I changed the code so that I skip the exceptions. Boiling it down to the simplest error (code snippet that throws the exception followed by error output):

```
ngv2 = CountVectorizer(decode_error='replace', analyzer='word', min_df=1, stop_words='english') 
try: 
  ngv2.fit_transform(sentence) 
except Exception as e: 
  print sentence, e.message
```

Which prints for an input of '[]p[]p[':

```
 empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? What error message do you see?

Comment: I get an exception message like this for a word like '[]p[]p[' empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

ngv2 = CountVectorizer(decode_error='replace', analyzer='word', min_df=1, stop_words='english')
    try:
        ngv2.fit_transform(sentence)
    except Exception as e:
        print sentence, e.message

Comment: Please see edit above.

Comment: You didn't say what version of python you're using ...